# How to delete all occurrences of a given key in a given linked list?

Tags: java

The action gets a Node and a number. It's supposed to return the node without the number.
I tried to do the code I added, but if you insert a node that starts with num (like num=2; Node = 2,3,4,5) it will delete everything but the number(2)
(if it doesn't start with it the code works just fine).

```
public static void DNumber(Node<Integer> list, int num) {
                Node<Integer> p = list;
                Node<Integer> dummy = new Node<Integer>(-999);
                Node<Integer> last = dummy;

                while (p != null) {
                    if (p.getValue() == num) {
                    last.setNext(p.getNext());
                    p.setNext(null);
                    p = last.getNext();  // Move to the next node after removal
                    } else {
                    last = p;
                    p = p.getNext();
                 }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Comment: Where should the "result" be? Your method does not have a return value.